# How to hide 'Export' from Ag-Grid Context Menu and replace 'Tool Panel ' instead?

Tags: ag-grid

I need to remove default export option present in ag-grid context menu and include the tool panel option in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something similar to @un.spike. I used params.context.gridApi instead of api because api didn't have those functions.

```
getContextMenuItems(params) {
return [
  'copy',
  'copyWithHeaders',
  'paste',
  'separator',
  {
    name: 'Export All',
    subMenu: [
      {
        name: 'CSV Export',
        action: () => {
          params.context.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv();
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Excel Export (.xlsx)',
        action: () => {
          params.context.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel();
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Excel Export (.xml)',
        action: () => {
          params.context.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({ exportMode: 'xml' });
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

}

and where I generated context

```
gridOptions = {
    context: this
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you ! (on ag-grid v17.0.0 / ag-grid-angular v17.0.0 / ag-grid-enterprise v17.0.0)

Answer (score 6):

you can [just override](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/#configuring-the-context-menu) `getContextMenuItems` function inside `gridOptions`

```
getContextMenuItems: this.getCustomContextMenuItems.bind(this)

getCustomContextMenuItems(params:GetContextMenuItemsParams) : MenuItemDef {
    let contextMenu: MenuItemDef = [];

    //... custom export just for info ... 
    contextMenu.push({
            name:"Export",
            subMenu:[
                {
                    name: "CSV Export (.csv)",
                    action: () => params.api.exportDataAsCsv()
                },
                {
                    name: "Excel Export (.xlsx)",
                    action: () => params.api.exportDataAsExcel()
                },
                {
                    name: "Excel Export (.xml)",
                    action: () => params.api.exportDataAsExcel({exportMode:"xml"})
                }
            ]
        })

    return contextMenu;
}
```

To add own logic in tool panel you have to :

> create a [custom](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-component/) `toolPanelComponent`, and within this component, you just need to execute `exportDataAsCsv()` or `exportDataAsExcel()`.

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";
import {IToolPanel, IToolPanelParams} from "ag-grid-community";

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-panel',
    template: `<button (click)="handleExportClick()">Export</button>`
})

export class CustomToolPanelComponent implements IToolPanel {
    private params: IToolPanelParams;

    agInit(params: IToolPanelParams): void {
        this.params = params;
    }

    handleExportClick(){
      this.params.api.exportDataAsCsv()
    }
}
```

> add `CustomToolPanelComponent` to `AgGridModule.withComponents` initialization in your `AppModule` (or whatever module ag-grid is injected)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    AgGridModule.withComponents([CustomToolPanelComponent])
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, CustomToolPanelComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> add `CustomToolPanelComponent` reference in `frameworkComponents` within `gridOptions`

```
this.frameworkComponents = { customToolPanel: CustomToolPanelComponent};
```

> add `CustomToolPanelComponent` reference (defined in `frameworkComponents`) to `sideBar.toolPanels` array

```
this.sideBar = {
  toolPanels: [
    ...
    {
      id: "customPanel",
      labelDefault: "Custom Panel",
      labelKey: "customPanel",
      iconKey: "custom-panel",
      toolPanel: "customToolPanel"
    }
  ]
};
```

[Here is a sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/n8ZAGWepekRPbpIllQme?p=preview)